# "without any core banking words"

Tags: word-choice, sentence

What is a better way of saying this sentence?

> The banker explained the working of bank in an easy way for a layman to understand **without any core banking words**.

The emphasis is on the highlighted part.

Comment: I think the easiest way it to put a period after *understand* and forget the highlighted part completely.  "The banker explained how the the bank works in terms a layman could easily understand."

Comment: What @Jim said. Obviously a layman won't be familiar with specialist banking terminology (I assume that's what OP means by *"core banking words"*). So if he can understand the explanation, it's already implicit that it doesn't use any obscure terminology. It doesn't need to be explicitly stated as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

..without any banking industry jargon

Jargon's definition from dictionary.reference.com/browse/jargon

"The language, especially the vocabulary, peculiar to a particular trade, profession, or group"

Comment: *Jargon* is one possibility, but firstly it's an inherently "loaded" term, and secondly it seems to me it's at least somewhat informal, if not actually "slangy". More "neutral" alternatives include, for example, *specialist banking terminology*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *Jargon* is jargon, while *specialist banking terminology* is businesspeak. (while *businesspeak* is jargon for bloated speech like *specialist terminology*). Some consider *jargon* slangy and *specialist terminology* neutral. Others consider *jargon* neutral and *specialist terminology* bloated. The two groups seriously dislike each other.

Comment: @SF. "Jargon" is the right word is this case because it means "[2: the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon)". "Specialist terminology" is a euphemism, like "intellectually challenged". Some jargon is slangy and some is not. "Argot", the jargon of the underworld, is "[an often more or less secret vocabulary and idiom peculiar to a particular group](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/argot?show=0&t=1352452615)", is always in-group slang.

Comment: @Bill Franke: Your idea that "specialist terminology" is a euphemism strikes me as truly bizarre. But as regards "jargon", I maintain that it's invariably used contemptuously, and I still think it's often an informal/ignorant way of referring to the language people use in specialised contexts.

Comment: Medical journal editors specifically refer to the specialist terminology used by MDs, microbiologists, & biochemists as **jargon** when they forbid their authors to use it. I can't agree that "specialist terminology" consists only of highfalutin technical terms like "Dative Alternation" (used the other day in a John Lawler answer). All the biomed people I edit for often use shorthand terms for procedures, tests, outcomes, etc. that are strictly jargon & not in dictionaries. We have differing cognitive maps. I traded emails with Bizzaro when he first started out. Maybe he rubbed off on me?

Comment: @fumblefingers, I agree that jargon can have negative connotations but the OP left the context of the example ambiguous.  Another word that could have been used is nomenclature but I thought that would be too clinical.  I chose jargon with no intented derogatory connotation.

Comment: @Kristina: I didn't think you intended the derogatory connotation, which is why I commented in the first place. It doesn't make your answer "incorrect", but I thought it should be noted. But apparently not everyone recognises the connotation, so I'll cite OED - *Applied **contemptuously** to any mode of speech abounding in unfamiliar terms, or peculiar to a particular set of persons, as the language of scholars or philosophers, the terminology of a science or art, or the cant of a class, sect, trade, or profession.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think we're more-or-less saying the same thing.  I support software for medical practices and deal with medical jargon every day - it's a fact of life.  As always, I respect and welcome your comments.

Comment: @Kristina: haha - have an upvote for successfully using the word "jargon" in a context where (I think) no negative connotations were either intended or perceived! But I bet you don't often tell your customers/users that many of what they consider their "important" words are in fact "jargon".

Comment: You're right. though we catch ourselves using software jargon while supporting our medical jargon-using user community. What a tangled web we weave... Lol!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I really don't think the author of The Jargon File ( http://catb.org/jargon/html/ ) really thought the name is contemptuous. Meanwhile, I'm fairly sure great quite a bit of people the type that are usual OED editors feel contemptuous about both the term and the people who use it neutrally. And vice versa.

Comment: @SF.: There will always be some people who don't register the same connotations as others for certain words. For example, some Australians use and perceive *"How are you, you old c*nt?"* as an affectionate greeting. In the case of "jargon", I believe OED is correct in that it's *usually* contemptuous. I also believe that even though Kristina intends nothing derogatory when she says they use "software jargon" when discussing "medical jargon" at work, she probably (wisely) avoids telling the *customers* their vocabulary is "jargon", ***just in case*** it causes offence sometimes.

Comment: Glad I'm not in Australia - I'd be totally offended being call old! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**"The banker explained how a bank works in layman's terms"**

and

**"The banker explained in layman's terms how a bank works"**

are shorter and incorporate the highlighted portion of your original sentence in the phrase *in layman's terms*.

Answer (score 3):

If the emphasis is meant to be on the bolded words (that is, the avoidance of jargon is the key message to be conveyed) then you could move it to a more prominent position.

> The banker needed no specialist vocabulary to explain the business in terms a layman could understand.